# Unable to Disable VERP in CIVIMAIL

Tags: civimail

As I know it, to disable VERP, navigate to Administer > CiviMail > Component Settings and disable 'Track replies using VERP in Reply-To header'.

However, even after this is disabled, Civimail continues to send email with VERP like Sender addresses (FROM: b.43.123.7a7d2f84f666abb6@xxxx.org). The email server raised the 550 error for invalid sender.

Do I have to change some other setting to fully disable the change in the sender address?
Thanks ahead.

Comment: did your setting got saved?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The settings were saved.

It seems that with or without the checkbox "Track replies using VERP in Reply-To header" would the "MAIL FROM:" header still be the same format i.e. b.43.123.7a7d2f84f666abb6@xxxx.org . 
Is that the correct behaviour of the setting?